# Restrict user to select business process flow stage manually

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm, business-process

I am trying to restrict user from manually selecting the business process stage.

I have already hidden all buttons (Next Stage, Finish, Previous Stage etc), using following,

```
document.getElementById("processActionsContainer");
```

Now I also want to restrict manual selection of stages of BPF. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you restrict buttons in Dynamics.
In fact `document.getElementById` is not allowed in dynamics itself. It is deprecated.

The way you are trying to limit stage change is not possible.

But the alternate way to achieve this is with Workflow.
For a Process to move from A to B will only happen when some fields are fields or some data is entered or some condition is matched.
Have a look at these articles which will give you more idea to perform your task.

[Link 1](https://www.inogic.com/blog/2018/08/validating-bpf-fields-to-restrict-stages-through-oob-workflow-in-dynamics-365/)

[Link 2](https://crmtipoftheday.com/941/tip-941-limit-who-can-change-the-stage-of-a-process-flow/)

[Link 3](https://community.dynamics.com/365/customerservice/f/dynamics-365-for-customer-service-forum/319795/how-to-stop-pause-prevent-previous-stage-button-on-business-process-flow-using-supported-way?pifragment-105564=2#responses)